# gnome-clocks 3.30 : prompting for permission to access geolocation -updated to 3.31.2

Tags: gnome-clocks

Since upgrade to 18.10 and gnome-clocks 3.30 I am prompted every time to confirm permission to access geolocation. I see that gnome-clocks has an entry in dconf but I don't see an entry for this permission.

Update : I built and install 3.31.2. Now the error message has more information

```
Failed to connect to GeoClue2 service:
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: 
Agent rejected 'org.gnome.clocks' for user '1000'. 
Please ensure that 'org.gnome.clocks' has installed 
a valid org.gnome.clocks.desktop file.
```

The dconf config through dconf dump shows this:
    [org/gnome/clocks]
    timer=uint32 1200
    alarms=[{'name': <'Alarm'>, 'id': 
    <'5a21b7926c6c553218b671425c316095'>, 'active': , 'hour': <18>, 
    'minute': <20>, 'days': <@ai []>}]
    world-clocks=@aa{sv} []

```
[org/gnome/clocks/state/window]
size=(870, 683)
state=132
panel-id='stopwatch'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: is it a snap version or APT?

Comment: It is APT. I've added an error message from gnome-clocks when started from command line.

Comment: can you attach the pic of prompt also please

Comment: https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/318 may this help?

Comment: I have built the latest from github and am getting a more informative error message. I have edited my question to include this new information.

Comment: do you have `dconf-editor` installed? can you check this path is available or not `org.gnome.clocks`

Comment: or check this file available in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd7I0.png  `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

Comment: @PRATAP I have added back to the question my previous info on dconf config. On my system, the schema file you reference has the same settings as shown in your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To /etc/geoclue/geoclue.conf add :

```
[org.gnome.clocks]
allowed=true
system=true
users=
```